# Making sure Mac M1 doesn't have tracking or screen-capturing software

Tags: mac, screen-capture, malware

I was given a new MacBook Air (M1) by my employer for work (from home), but I also want to use it as my main personal laptop as well, since having 2 machines doesn't seem necessary.
There a chance there might be some software that "spies" on me and while I don't do anything illegal or not appropriate (like working for competitors or doing personal things during work time) it's an uncomfortable feeling to know that they might know/see my personal notes or files, etc.

BTW, I'm not prohibited from reinstalling software, creating users, etc.
With these tools at my disposal, what can I do to make sure there's no tracking software?
I don't even care so much about network traffic as about screen capturing, since it's way more confidential.

I already started by erasing the disk and re-installing Big Sur. I checked that SIP is enabled.
What else do you think I can do?
PS. I do have another mac to do the 'target mode' thing I read about, but didn't do that yet.

Comment: If you wiped the disk and reinstalled the OS, then that guarantees that no other software will be present.

Comment: JSYK Your employer can show up where you live and demand you immediately turn over company property. You could possibly end up in jail if you refuse to. You should never use company properly for personal use!

Comment: It's not yours, why would you treat it like it were?

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified that the company doesn't have such strict policies, i.e. previously I was using my person laptop for work and it was totally fine. They just give you the hardware and as long as you do your job and return that hardware when you quit or when they need it, everything is cool.

Comment: It's not a question of what policy the company has, it's whether or not it's a good idea.  It's not.  Don't do it.

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm clearly missing something, do you mind sharing your thoughts why it's not a good idea?

Comment: It doesn't need to go any further than "it's not yours", but the comment from @user3439894 is highly relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your employer installs management software, you should not use it as a personal machine, or do so with the *expectation* it's being tracked. The computer is your employer's property so if they tell you to run a certain enrollment process you should not try to work around this.

If it's appropriate to use this as your personal computer, you can and should follow the steps to wipe your computer: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212030. This will ensure you know all the software installed.

Comment: Thanks! If it wasn't clear, I meant I want to use it for personal web browsing and stuff like that after work, which I told our IT in advance and there are no problems with that.